# create campaign with mailchimp api v2 using drewm wrapper

Tags: php, api, mailchimp

I have some api 1.3 deprecated pages which i am needing to update, but am struggling to find many working php examples for v 2.0

I have found the [drewm wrapper](https://github.com/drewm/mailchimp-api/blob/master/src/Drewm/MailChimp.php) which I have got to work for list subscribe etc, but I am having a problem with creating a campaign.

Here is a code snippet, which I believe conforms to the expected input, but when I run it, i get the message Invalid MailChimp List ID, though i know it is correct

```
<?php 

$options[] = array(
      'list_id' => 'list id',
      'subject' => 'Test Campaign '.date('m/d/y g:ia'),
      'from_email' => 'email@hotmail.com',
      'from_name' => 'Test Sender',
      'to_name' => 'Test Recipient',
      'template_id' => '123456',
      'title' => 'example title'
    );

$content[] = array(
      'text' => 'example text'
    );

$MailChimp = new \Drewm\MailChimp('api key');
$result = $MailChimp->call("campaigns/create", array(
                                    'type' => 'regular',
                                    'options' => $options,
                                    'content' => $content
                            )
                          );
    var_dump($result);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

...it was the square brackets I had mistakenly added when setting up the php variables

here is a working snippet...

```
<?php 

$options = array(
  'list_id' => 'list id',
  'subject' => 'Test Campaign '.date('m/d/y g:ia'),
  'from_email' => 'email@hotmail.com',
  'from_name' => 'Test Sender',
  'to_name' => 'Test Recipient',
  'template_id' => '123456',
  'title' => 'example title'
);

$content = array(
  'text' => 'example text'
);

$MailChimp = new \Drewm\MailChimp('api key');
$result = $MailChimp->call("campaigns/create", array(
                                'type' => 'regular',
                                'options' => $options,
                                'content' => $content
                        )
                      );
var_dump($result);

 ?>
```